# Share aspx file in two solution

Tags: visual-studio, file, asp.net, share

how can I share one or two aspx file in two separated solution 
that if i change aspx file in both solution apply changes.
Is it possible in visual studio 2008 or in Team foundation server?

Answer (score 0):

From the Add Existing Dialog for one of the projects, select your file. Click the arrow next to the Add button. Select Add As Link.

Comment: tanx for your response
but i can not add as link file in website projects but in web application project i can!
another problem is that if i add an aspx file as a link in the web app projects and run the web site I could not open the added file in my web site and the bleow error raise:
"The resource cannot be found." 
do u have any solution for this problem?